# SWIFT - Cannot assign value of type '[(String, [String : Any])]' to type '[String : [String : Any]]'

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

How do I get rid of the "()" on the first value so I can assign to the next variable?

This is how I initialize my dictionary:

```
var imagedata: [String: [String: Any]] = [:]
```

I load data into the dictionary and then I sort it

```
imagedata = Array(imagedata).sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })
```

but it gives me a value of type '[(String, [String : Any])]' instead of '[String : [String : Any]]' so it can't be assigned.

Comment: what is the data structure of `imagedata` variable inside `Array(imagedata)`?

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition and the result of your "fake-sort" is an array of tuples rather than a dictionary.

Comment: This is imagedata: ["10October201611": ["images": [<UIImage: 0x7fdb88f84540>, {500, 500}, <UIImage: 0x7fdb88c9a740>, {1024, 768}], "count": 2, "date": "Monday:10-October-2016-11:14:48AM"], ..."10October201608": ["images": [<UIImage: 0x7fdb88e5df20>, {1024, 768}, <UIImage: 0x7fdb88f7cbb0>, {1024, 768}], "count": 2, "date": "Monday:10-October-2016-08:18:52PM"]]

Answer (score 1):

`var imagedata: [String: [String: Any]] = [:]` //imagedata is an dictionary.

`imagedata = Array(imagedata).sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })` Here you have added imagedata to Array and sorted. Because we can't sort dictionary.

The result of `sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })` will be array with original array object types. So it returns `[(String, [String : Any])]`. So we can't assign to imagedata variable.

Actually `Array(imagedata).sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })` does nothing. Because array has only one object. So it returns same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You sort it, but you can't store the result back to `imagedata` like this because `Array(imagedata).sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })` creates a (sorted) `array`, while `imagedata` has the type of a `dictionary`.

This will give you a compilation error: `imagedata = Array(imagedata).sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })`

While this won't `Array(imagedata).sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })`

This tells us, that the problem is not the sort method, but the variable we are using to store the result.

**Dictionaries have their own `sort` method, which you can use.** But trying to assign an `array` (the value returned from any `sort` method) to the `dictionary` (`imagedata`) will always fail.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of how you could use the `sort` method on your dictionary and work with the returned value:

```
var imagedata: [String: [String: Any]] = [:]
imagedata["a"] = ["Hello": 2]
imagedata["b"] = ["World": UIImage()]
imagedata["c"] = ["Foo": "Bar"]
imagedata["d"] = ["LifeQuest": 42]

print(imagedata)
// prints the content of the dictionary. Dictionaries are un-ordered, so you may always get different results here
// ["b": ["World": <UIImage: 0x60000009ea00>, {0, 0}], "a": ["Hello": 2], "d": ["LifeQuest": 42], "c": ["Foo": "Bar"]]

let orderedKeysAndValues = imagedata.sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })
for (key, value) in orderedKeysAndValues {
    print("key: \(key)")
    print("value: \(value)")
}

// the content of the loop will print
// key: a
// value: ["Hello": 2]
// key: b
// value: ["World": <UIImage: 0x60000009ba80>, {0, 0}]
// key: c
// value: ["Foo": "Bar"]
// key: d
// value: ["LifeQuest": 42]
```

Comment: *Dictionaries have their own sort method*. No, they haven't. Strictly spoken dictionaries cannot be sorted at all because a dictionary is an **unordered** collection type.

Comment: @vadian Yes they have [Link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted). 

Although the return type is not a `dictionary` you can call `sort` on dictionaries.

Comment: The return type of your linked method is *A sorted array*, not a dictionary. That's why I wrote **strictly spoken**.

Comment: Still, any object of the type `dictionary` has a `sort` method. It doesn't matter what it returns. That's my point. OP is clearly trying to sort his dictionary by turning it into an array, which is not necessary. He can use the return value of the `sort` method, to retrieve the data as he needs it.

Maybe I should update my answer to make it clear.

Comment: It does matter what it returns, that's what the question is about. **You cannot sort a dictionary and assign it back to a dictionary variable** regardless of whether the return type is an array of tuples or an array of whatever.

Comment: I never said that you can sort an dictionary (and assign it back). I just said, you can call sort directly on a dictionary object, which you opposed.

My answer doesn't seem to be precise enough, so I will update it.